# MySQL ошибка: unknown option '--no-beep'

Tags: mysql, резервное-копирование

Столкнулся с ошибкой: `unknown option '--no-beep'`, вычитал, что нужна правка конфигурационного файла `my.ini`.
Но дело в том, что БД много и расположены они в разных городах России.
Задача простая: Реализация выгрузки.
Вопрос: Есть-ли альтернативный выход не прибегая к стороннему ПО?
Как обойти этот `--no-beep` при использовании `mysqldump.exe`?
Версия MySQL: 5.5.29.

Comment: `Столкнулся с ошибкой` - уточните, в какой момент. `--no-beep` - это опция штатного клиента командной строки. Как она затесалась в секцию параметров сервиса? `Есть-ли альтернативный выход не прибегая к стороннему ПО?` Не, ну какая может быть альтернатива правильной настройке?

Comment: Вот в этой строке: `"c:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe" -u[user] -p[password] --host=127.0.0.1 [db_name] [table_name] > c:\backups\dump_table_name.sql`

Comment: Создайте свой собственный конфигурационный файл и используйте его при выгрузке. Или включите в строку запуска опцию `--no-defaults` - при этом конфигурационный файл игнорируется,- и все необходимые опции указывайте в командной строке.

Comment: Публиковал ответ на свой дже вопрос, примерно в это же время, что и вы свой комментарий, видимо. Может ваш комментарий в ответ сделать?
Ведь это решило проблему.

Comment: А смысл? ответ есть, ответ по существу - и достаточно. А кто его запостил - какая разница?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ кроется в одном из обращений пользователя к разработчикам mySQL: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83334
Надо просто вписать параметр: `--no-defaults` - (*Don't read default options from any option file*).
Рабочий пример:

```
"c:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe" --no-defaults -u[user] -p[password] --host=127.0.0.1 [db_name] [table_name] > c:\backups\dump_table_name.sql
```